# Duplicate key error return

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am working with mysqli database and have `email` set as a primary key. Now when I attempting to `execute()` a query on the database, on duplicate entries the database will reject it but I don't get an error returned back. `mysqli->errno = 0` however `mysqli->affected_rows = -1`. How do I get the error that is being returned by the database?

```
INSERT INTO user (Status,Email,Lastname,Firstname,Password) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Status = VALUES(Status),Email = VALUES(Email),Lastname = VALUES(Lastname),Firstname = VALUES(Firstname),Password = VALUES(Password)
```

Comment: Since you're using `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`, you don't get an error when there's a duplicate.

Comment: @Barmar definitely makes sense. Thank you.